# zpt xml-schema definition

Tags: xsd, zope, template-tal, zpt, template-metal

Where can i find xml-schema definition for ZPT attribute language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK ZPT doesn't use an XML Schema definition. Why do you want the XSD of ZPT? If you want to get an overview of ZPT you can have a look to the [documentation](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/zpt.html) for the chameleon implementation of ZPT. It's quite comprehensive.

Comment: I need ZPT XML-schema for validating and code-completing in Intellij IDEA.

Comment: ZPT is valid XML, you should make sure your IDE treats it as XML and you'll get basic XML validation. However you won't have validation for the specifics of ZPT. In my case I don't miss ZPT auto-completion because it's quite concise.